Navigating Android device directories with Appium
I need to access my Android device's files through Appium.
However, after the AndroidDriver is initialized and the application is launched in Android Studio, its current directory System.getProperty("user.dir") is still the project code's folder on my computer. The instruction is called under a @Test.
Was it the wrong way to check current location on the Android device?
What are the functions I could use to reach Documents/Download/Data, etc. ? Where are we when entering @Test after device initialization?
I am writing in Java and using Maven.
